# Cucumber skip test step

Tags: ruby, frameworks, cucumber, bdd

Can anyone let me know how do I skip a test step in cucumber?

I have a system pop up coming up that I am disabling by pressing "OK" on it, the same is not reliably popping up each time.

I want to skip that particular step when the pop up does not appear and proceed to the next step in the scenario.

Any idea how to do it. I am not sure, how do I implement the `next if` code.

I am currently using

```
popups = wait_true {exists { find_element(name: "OK") }}
  if popups
    wait_true {exists { find_element(name: "OK").click }}
  else
    puts "Pop up not available, hence proceeding to next step"
  end
end
```

But there must be a better way to do this?

Comment: Is there anything event-driven that you can check against, rather than polling? Or, could you consistently say that the popup will/will not appear on a given test scenario? In other words, when and why does the popup appear?

Comment: I am waiting for the OTP & once the OTP is received, a system alert is being shown(which I cannot disable). this pop up sometimes appears and doesnt appear and I have no control on it. I tried `autoGrantpermissions`, but when this pop up appears, the test case fails, in case I dont have a code to disable it. 

Now, What I wanted is, either I have a `if else` condition i.e `if exist? click` else `puts proceed` or have a cucumber/ruby code, that skips the step if element not available and proceed to next step.I tried using `next if response.code == "500" || response.code == "400"`, but in vain

Comment: I can validate this step if pop up appears, click on "ok" else, go to the next step or display "pop up" not displayed. The code which i put above, doesnt work consistently. I wanted a better logic.... if you could help

Comment: Or should I sleep() and get the page source? and validate if find_element.include? OK?

Comment: So it sounds like you don't know how/why the message does/doesn't appear ... without figuring this out, you won't be able to implement an "optimum" solution - and should instead resort back to some sort of polling. What is `wait_true`? Does it have a default timeout, or can you supply it one as a parameter?

Comment: Thats a default time out of 30seconds(which you can change), for the element to appear, I didnt want to add an additional step of sleep everytime. For now, probably ill, use `find_element().displayed?` and rescue = false` to handle the thing, but I might want to figure out a better solution for all these unreliable pop ups.